# What's the difference between UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateSelected?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to set a state for UIButton.

But i don't know the difference between the `UIControlStateHighlighted` and `UIControlStateSelected`.

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They can mean whatever you want them to, but in general they mean the following:

Highlighted = The user is currently interacting with something that will change once they stop interacting (e.g. holding down a button)

Selected = The item is current the active item in a group (e.g. The selected item in a segmented control).  This can only be achieved by setting it programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

- `UIControlStateHighlighted` = it highlights the button with some flash(in button background) when the  user taps.
- `UIControlStateSelected` = it highlights nothing to that button.

Answer (score 2):

From the official doc:

> **UIControlStateHighlighted** Highlighted state of a control. A control
>   enters this state when a touch enters and exits during tracking and
>   when there is a touch up event. You can retrieve and set this value
>   through the highlighted property.
>
> **UIControlStateSelected** Selected state of a control. For many controls,
>   this state has no effect on behavior or appearance. But other
>   subclasses (for example, the UISegmentedControl class) may have
>   different appearance depending on their selected state. You can
>   retrieve and set this value through the selected property.

Your button get `highlighted` in reaction of a touch event. It could then be on a `selected` state within a group (for segmented control).

Answer (score 1):

Highlighted is typically applied transiently when the control is being touched, selected is a more permanent state. Imagine a checkbox type button which dimmed while it was being touched - dimming is highlighted, ticked is selected, unticked is unselected.

Typically you'd never set highlighted status manually as the system will be setting/unsettling it in response to touches, whereas selected is safer. This particularly applies to buttons.